# Salt-api and restcherrypy permission denied error

Tags: salt-stack, cherrypy

I am trying to set up a new salt master and want to use salt-api.

I am following the guide here

https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/netapi/all/salt.netapi.rest_cherrypy.html#a-rest-api-for-salt

However after completing the seven steps i am getting permission denied, errors

> 2023-07-28 10:59:57,541 [cherrypy.error   :213 ][ERROR   ][15068]
> [28/Jul/2023:10:59:57] ENGINE Error in 'start' listener <bound method
> Server.start of <cherrypy._cpserver.Server object at 0x7fa6294701f0>>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py", line 230,
> in publish
> output.append(listener(*args, **kwargs))   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cpserver.py", line 179, in
> start
> self.httpserver, self.bind_addr = self.httpserver_from_self()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cpserver.py", line 170,
> in httpserver_from_self
> httpserver = _cpwsgi_server.CPWSGIServer(self)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cpwsgi_server.py", line 99,
> in **init**
> self.ssl_adapter = adapter_class(   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cheroot/ssl/builtin.py", line 226, in
> **init**
> self.context.load_cert_chain(certificate, private_key) PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
>
> 2023-07-28 10:59:57,542 [cherrypy.error   :213 ][ERROR   ][15068]
> [28/Jul/2023:10:59:57] ENGINE Shutting down due to error in start
> listener: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py", line 268,
> in start
> self.publish('start')   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py", line 248,
> in publish
> raise exc cherrypy.process.wspbus.ChannelFailures: PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
>
> 2023-07-28 10:59:57,543 [cherrypy.error   :213 ][INFO    ][15068]
> [28/Jul/2023:10:59:57] ENGINE Bus STOPPING 2023-07-28 10:59:57,543
> [cherrypy.error   :213 ][INFO    ][15068] [28/Jul/2023:10:59:57]
> ENGINE HTTP Server None already shut down 2023-07-28 10:59:57,543
> [cherrypy.error   :213 ][INFO    ][15068] [28/Jul/2023:10:59:57]
> ENGINE Bus STOPPED 2023-07-28 10:59:57,543 [cherrypy.error   :213
> ][INFO    ][15068] [28/Jul/2023:10:59:57] ENGINE Bus EXITING
> 2023-07-28 10:59:57,544 [cherrypy.error   :213 ][INFO    ][15068]
> [28/Jul/2023:10:59:57] ENGINE Bus EXITED

Comment: have you check what user it's running salt-master and salt-api in order to check the permissions for that user to read the certificates files to the config of cherrypy with salt?